# Problem with the layers display KML stored in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I have a problem with the layers display KML stored in GeoServer. Google Earth shows me the study area, but the layer doesn't appear. However, I can see the layer when I "click" in OpenLayers.

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: what sort of layer? what url do you use? are there any errors in the GeoServer log?

Comment: I suppose that the KML file contains a link to your GeoServer. Perhaps Google Earth can't access your server.